# Chain multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Depending on conditions, I'm trying to chain multiple `WHERE` clauses to the `TransactionDataList` variable. Please advise what's the right way to do this.

I'm getting this error:

> Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Code:

```
List<Transaction> QueriedTransactionList;
QueriedTransactionList = db.Transactions.ToList();

List<TransactionViewModel> TransactionDataList = QueriedTransactionList.Select(x => new TransactionViewModel
{
    TTransactionID = x.TTransactionID,
    BatchID = x.BatchID,
    TransactionDateTime = x.TransactionDateTime,
    TransactionStatus = x.TransactionStatus,
    TaxPayerName = x.Card.TaxPayer.TaxPayerName,
    TaxPayerEmail = x.Card.TaxPayer.TaxPayerEmail
}).GroupBy(x => x.BatchID).Select(x => x.LastOrDefault()).OrderByDescending(x => x.TTransactionID).ToList();

if (Request.QueryString["Port"] != "")
{
    int Port = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Port"]);
    TransactionDataList = TransactionDataList.Where(x => x.Card.PortID == Port);
}

if (Request.QueryString["Status"] != "")
{
    string Status = Request.QueryString["Status"];
    TransactionDataList = TransactionDataList.Where(x => x.TransactionStatus == Status);
}

if (Request.QueryString["TIN"] != "")
{
    string TIN = Request.QueryString["TIN"];
    TransactionDataList = TransactionDataList.Where(x => x.Card.TaxPayerTIN == TIN);
}
```

Comment: A couple of side notes: 1. Never use `Convert.ToInt32` unless you are sure that the value is, infact, an int32. Querystring value contains strings and users can easily change them - this is an exception waiting to happen. 2. You might want to rethink this approach and create the predicate first, and only once it's done apply the where clause. This might have better performance since you will do all the filtering in one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `List<T>` is an `IEnumerable<T>` but an `IEnunumerable<T>` is not guarenteed to be a list. The return type from `Select` and `Where` is `IEnumerable<T>` and cannot be assigned to `TransactionDataList`.

Change

```
List<TransactionViewModel> TransactionDataList = QueriedTransactionList.Select...
```

to

```
IEnumerable<TransactionViewModel> TransactionDataList = QueriedTransactionList.Select...
```

and the errors will go away. If you want access to methods provided by `IList<T>`, you will need to convert back to list using the `ToList` extension method.